# VSCode error when injecting an external Angular service

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I get the following error when hovering over `@Component` in VSCode when injecting an external service: `[Angular] Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent in /angular/nx/string-utils/apps/strings-test/src/app/app.component.ts: (?).` But everything works fine if I run the app. Any suggestions about how can I get rid of this error?

Those are the relevant files:

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StringsService } from '@string-utils/strings-module/src/strings.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private stringsService: StringsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.stringsService.toUpperCase('Marius'));
  }
}
```

`app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NxModule } from '@nrwl/nx';
import { StringsModuleModule } from '@string-utils/strings-module';
import { StringsService } from '@string-utils/strings-module/src/strings.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, NxModule.forRoot(), StringsModuleModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`strings-module.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { StringsService } from '@string-utils/strings-module/src/strings.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [StringsService]
})
export class StringsModuleModule { }
```

Comment: Are there typings that need to be install along with the `@string-utils` package?

Comment: Nope, there are no typings needed, I have the src  directly in typescript

Comment: Sometimes VS code ends up being a little confused when you install packages, restarting the typescript mostly solves this for me. Try doing so from the command palette, cmd + shift + p will get you there :)

Comment: Restarting the tsservice/vscode doesn't help. The error is not a TS error it comes from Angular Language Service, I guess